# In swift, prepare is invoked before didSelectRowAt

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to build a tableview in swift, when a cell is tapped, another view which contains the details of that cell will appear. I used prepare method to send an object to the second view to show the details. 
However, when I tapped a cell, the second view will show information about the previously tapped cell.
I used the didSelectRowAt to catch the current tapped cell, and used the prepare method to send the object.
Is there any chance I can use one of these two methods perform this task correctly?

Any hints would be most appreciated.

Comment: what is the "prepare method"?

Comment: Don't attach a segue to the cell. Instead, invoke the segue from the ode of your didSelectRow(at:) method, as shown in @DonMag's answer.

Comment: If all you really need from `didSelectRowAt` is the selected index path in order to retrieve some data from the data source, you could also probably bypass the `didSelect` method and retrieve that index path in `prepare` using `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow`.

Answer (score 2):

Keep the segue defined, but do not connect it to selecting a row. Instead, you can (for example):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("mySegueIdentifier", sender: tableView)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "mySegueIdentifier" {
        // do your normal stuff here....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

step1: connect the whole table to the view
[image]

step2: call below function in didSelectedRow

[image]